# converge of a improper integral $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}$

Tags: analysis

I am trying to show $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}$ converge. But I cannot remember a suitable testing rule for this one. Could anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Is this a **real** analysis problem? Then we have trouble, since $x^3-x$ is negative in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well, it has the tag "analysis".

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+1%2Fsqrt%5Bx%5E3-x%5D

Comment: well, I just do the qualify exam from http://www.math.neu.edu/sites/default/files/users/g.horton/An1QE10%2C%20January%202011.pdf which is the last problem. Since it is only  an analysis I exam, I don't think it will involve complex analysis. Maybe it is a typo? Is that possible to prove it by replacing it as $x-x^3$?

Comment: Yes, if we replace $x^3-x$ by $x-x^3$, we get a real integral that converges. Split it into two parts, say $0$ to $1/2$ and $1/2$ to $1$. For each part, use estimates, or some other technique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Andre. My question is actually the estimates or the other technique you mentioned.

Comment: Could I multiply the integrant by $\sqrt{x}$ around $0$ and by $\sqrt{1-x}$ around $1$ to show the limit is finite and then to say the integral converge?

Comment: Substituting $x=\sin(a)$ helps? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+pi%2F2+of+1%2Fsqrt%5Bsin%28x%29%5D

Comment: Well, probably. But I am more concern with a proof rather than an accurate result.

Comment: This is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in disguise.